# DAX Current Year Count in Calculate measure

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I try to get a very simple count that checks for today's year.
`DIM_Project.StartDate` is of type `DATE` and there are multiple records `%ProjKey` with a `StartDate` within the year 2019.

Any idea why I get no results at all with the following DAX formula, only data within the same table:

```
ProjectCount = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(DIM_Project[%ProjKey]),
    DIM_Project[Startdate] = YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Anything I miss here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing date (`DIM_Project[Startdate]`) with integer (value returned by `YEAR()` function) doesn't seems right. What about this code?

```
ProjectCount = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(DIM_Project[%ProjKey]),
    YEAR(DIM_Project[Startdate]) = YEAR(TODAY()))
```